# something wrong with mouse wheel

Tags: 18.04, mouse

This is not the first time, I used to use ubuntu a few year ago and have the same issue.

The mouse wheel remembered the last of its activity.

I'm using the latest distro of Ubuntu 18.04

For example: in chrome, I scroll up a range, then back to visual code, even I scroll it up or down, it always scroll up a range same with I do in chrome.

It happen once everytime time then it's back to normal.

My mouse is work perfectly in window.
Hope you can understand.